# How to connect mongodb to neo4j

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I am trying to connect mongodb data to neo4j.
I tried with this code "CALL apoc.mongodb.get('mongodb://localhost:27017','test','test',{name:'testDocument'})" in Neo4j.
But I get an error as
There is no procedure with the name `apoc.mongodb.get` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
I had added APOC jar files in Neo4j plugins and I gone through this link http://indexoutofrange.com/Neo4jStoredProceduresWindows/

still Iam unable to connect.
can someone please explain what shall i do to get this started.
Thanks

Comment: What is the result of running `CALL dbms.procedures()`? Do you see `apoc.mongodb.get` in the list?

Comment: yeah i have run the command CALL dbms.procedures(), in that i got apoc.mongodb.get

Comment: I have run this command "CALL apoc.mongodb.get('mongodb://localhost:27017','test','test',{name:'testDocument'})" , I am getting error like this "Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.mongodb.get`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create MongoDBClientWrapper instance"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to copying the APOC jar file to `$NEO4J_HOME/plugins` you'll also need to copy the mongo specific jar files into `$NEO4J_HOME/plugins`. For example:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
cp target/dependency/mongodb*.jar target/dependency/bson*.jar $NEO4J_HOME/plugins/
```

More information available in the docs [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_interacting_with_mongodb)

Comment: Hi,William Thanks for your response, i have added already these"mongodb-driver-3.2.2,neo4j-apoc-examples-1.0,bson-3.0.0,apoc-3.0.4.2-all ,neo4j-apoc-procedures-3.0.4.2 "mongo jar files  into $NEO4J_HOME/plugins is it  right  but i am unable to connect mongodb to NEO4J. what might be the issue that occured to connect..?please favour me for solving the error Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I know this was made 5 years ago but this is for anyone else (like myself) who's looking for an answer.

The URI should look something like this:

CALL apoc.mongo.find("mongodb://localhost:port/databaseName.collectionName")